# Stationary Obversers in Brinkmann Coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, vectors, velocity, observers

The four-velocity of a stationary observer is defined as $U^{u}$ = $\left (\dot{t},0,0,0  \right )$, where t is the time coordinate in some four-dimensional coordinate system, and overdot represents derivative with respect to proper time. Is it possible to represent this four-velocity in Brinkmann coordinates?

The four-velocity of an observer in Brinkmann coordinates would be generally represented as $U^{u}$ = $\left (\dot{u},\dot{v},\dot{x},\dot{y}  \right )$, where $u$ = $\left ( \frac{ct - z}{\sqrt{2}} \right )$ and $v$ = $\left ( \frac{ct + z}{\sqrt{2}} \right )$, representing the retarded and advanced time respectively.

It would seem then that for a stationary observer that the four velocity in these coordinates becomes:

$U^{u}$ = $\left (\dot{u},\dot{v},0,0  \right )$

Where $\dot{u}$ = $\dot{v}$ = $\dot{t}$ in Cartesian coordinates. Is this correct, or is it impossible to represent stationary observers in the Brinkmann coordinate system, requiring a transformation to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: It is not about coordinates but about spacetime. If a spacetime does not have a timelike Killing vector field, then there would be no stationary observer. If such field exists you can use any appropriate set of coordinates to describe such observers.

Comment: I see. For these coordinates, u is often taken as the time coordinate, since its signature can become timelike. So, if we have a Killing vector for u, then we could have stationary observers?